# Connection to EC2 instance from Jenkins fails : Host key verification failed

Tags: linux, jenkins, amazon-ec2, groovy, devops

I'm trying to automate a deployment with Jenkins to an EC2 instance for the first time.

I have installed `tomcat8` in the EC2 instance and changed the permissions of the `tomcat8/webapps` folder to 777 (`$ chmod 777 webapps`).

The `.ssh` from EC2 is in the `known_hosts` file.

I'm able to connect and copy the `.war` file into the server folder using `scp` from my console but it fails during the automation.

```
$ scp -i /Users/Shared/Jenkins/aws.pem /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/fully-automated/builds/28/archive/webapp/target/webapp.war ec2-user@35.158.118.56:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps

== copies the *.war file to tomcat8/webapps ==
```

In Jenkins, I am getting:

```
[Deploy to Staging] + scp -i /Users/Shared/Jenkins/aws.pem /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/fully-automated/builds/28/archive/webapp/target/webapp.war ec2-user@35.158.118.56:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps
[Deploy to Staging] Host key verification failed.
[Deploy to Staging] lost connection
```

The command from the console and from the Groovy Jenkins file is the exact same. Why would it work from my machine and not from Jenkins?

Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  tools {
    maven 'localMaven'
  }

  parameters {
    string(name: 'production', defaultValue: '54.93.78.130', description: 'Staging server')
    string(name: 'staging', defaultValue: '35.158.118.56', description: 'Production server')
  }

  triggers {
    pollSCM('* * * * *')
  }

  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh 'mvn clean package'
      }
      post {
        success {
          echo 'Now Archiving...'
          archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/target/*.war'
        }
      }
    }

    stage('Deployments') {
      parallel {
        stage('Deploy to Staging') {
          steps {
            sh "scp -i /Users/Shared/Jenkins/aws.pem /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/fully-automated/builds/28/archive/webapp/target/*.war ec2-user@${params.staging}:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps"
          }
        }

        stage('Deploy to Production') {
          steps {
            sh "scp -i /Users/Shared/Jenkins/aws.pem /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/fully-automated/builds/28/archive/webapp/target/*.war ec2-user@${params.production}:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps"
          }
        }
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common mistake many people perform. You have given permission to your "USERNAME" to access EC2 not "JENKINS" user. Just do the same thing, but this time do it for Jenkins user.

Jenkins has its own user called "jenkins" which you can observe in users folder, create the ssh key here and pass this to EC2 and everything should work fine :)

For conformation, just ssh into the server using your username and give it a try with Jenkins username it will not work until you do it the above changes

Hope this helps :)

Comment: hi @rohit thanks for your answer! I have two users inside the Jenkins `users` folder: admin and jen.lijo (me). I don't recall giving any specific permission to my username... I created the instances, added a security group and a key pair, and use that key to connect to it. Could you please detail how to give those permissions to Jenkins? any documentation you could provide? :)

Comment: @catch22 you are looking into the application users ... I'm talking about the System users... if you look under /home/jenkins ....this user should be available and  you have to create the ssh keys from here

Comment: `/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/users/` this is where I am looking.. and only `admin` and `jen.lijo` :/

Comment: lol ... can you confirm 2 things for me ... which OS are you using ?? and admin  and jen.lijo are these the users you use to login into jenkins ??

Comment: Your hints about the username led me to a temporary solution. Solved it changing the `jenkins` username to my system username and it worked: https://biolinh.wordpress.com/2016/10/18/change-user-running-jenkins/

Comment: great :) just try getting it to work with jenkins user, so that it isn't bound to anyone person

Comment: what is user folder here ,is it HOST VM user folder or Jenkins Server user Folder?